# Getting "try reformatting" in play console help page

Tags: google-play-console

i am getting an error in play console help page "try reformatting even though i fill up all the details but in location i am getting this error, i even change the country and browser but it is not working

i lost my upload key, without that i can't publish new updates, please help me
[screenshot of the page's error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS7Pu.png)

tried changing country, fill up all the details, and even change my browser as well.

Comment: Please make sure you're not connected to any vpn

Comment: Having the same error

Comment: Same problem here ... tried with different browsers.

Comment: It seems to be a temporary issue with the "Your location" form field. When I choose a country from the initial list, I am left with choosing between the country I have just chosen and "Select one". The initial list is gone. I have the feeling this is a UX bug on Google's end.

Comment: Does anyone know when this error will be fixed?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, still location dropdown is not working

Comment: Getting this issue trying to submit the Brazilian tax verification form https://support.google.com/paymentscenter/contact/GPBR_SVID_Initial_Form